# How does hash table work for dynamically lengthed array?

Tags: linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

In cases where the length of an array is fixed, it makes sense to me that the time complexity of a hash table lookup is O(1). However, I don't get how hash tables work for dynamically lengthed arrays such as a linked list. Direct indexing is clearly not possible when elements of an array are scattered all over the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, a hash table where the keys are implemented as a linked list would *not* be `O(1)`, because the key search is `O(n)`. However, linked lists are not the only expandable structure.

You could, for example, use a resizable vector, such as one that doubles in size each time it needs to expand. That *is* directly addressable without an `O(n)` search so satisfies that `O(1)` condition.

Keep in mind that resizing the vector would almost certainly change the formula that allocates items into individual buckets of that vector, meaning there's a good chance you'd have to recalculate the buckets into which every *existing* item is stored.

That would still *amortise* to O(1), even with a single `insert` operation possibly having to do an O(n) reallocation, since the reallocations would be infrequent, and likely to become *less* frequent over time as the vector gets larger.

Answer (score 1):

You can still map the elements of a linked list to a hash table. Yes, it's true we do not know the size of the list beforehand, so we cannot use a C-style or non-expandable array to represent our hash table. This is where vectors come into play (or ArrayList if you're from Java).

A crash course on vectors will be: if there is no more space in the current array, make a new array of double size, and copy the previous elements into it. More formally, if we want to insert `n+1` elements into an array of size `n`, then it will make a new array of size `2n`. For the next overflow, it will create an array of size `4n` and so on.

The following code can map values of a linked list into a hash table.

```
void map(Node* root) {
    vector<int> hash;

    while(root){
        hash[root->val]++;
        root = root->next;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<hash.size(); i++){
        cout<<hash[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```